# How to run GDAL (ogr2ogr) in Java to convert Shapefiles to GeoJSON

Tags: java, json, shapefile, gdal

I'm a beginner at programming and get pretty confused when trying to use external libraries. I have my maps in shapefiles that I convert to GeoJSON using the website Mapshaper.org, and only then can i read the map from my Java application.

I want the user to be able to import a shapefile directly so I found out about GDAL [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) that has [Java bindings](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/GdalOgrInJava), and can make this conversion with a single command such as:

`$ ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -t_srs crs:84 [name].geojson [name].shp`

but I have no idea how to use this from my program.

Can someone provide me with an example of how to implement this? How should I import GDAL to my project? I'm using LibGDX if that's of any help.

In the end, all i need is a way to convert shapefile to GeoJSON directly on my application so the user can add new maps himself, so any suggestion is welcome.

Thank you so much!

Comment: See http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/tutorial.html

Comment: I am strongly looking for the answer for this question... +1...

Comment: could you finde a solution for that?

Answer (score 8):

First you need to install the Java Bindings (see [here](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/GdalOgrInJava) at the bottom). Than download the ogr2ogr.java from [here](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/browser/trunk/gdal/swig/java/apps/ogr2ogr.java) (scroll down -> download original format -> put it into your project folder).
Than it gets quite easy. You just cann call ogr2ogr.java's main method. `ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -t_srs crs:84 [name].geojson [name].shp` :

```
String[] cmd = {"-t_srs", "CRS:84", "-f", "GeoJSON","[name].geojson","[name].shp"};

ogr2ogr.main(cmd);
```

Comment: On the page [Build Instructions for GDAL/OGR In Java (Windows)](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/GdalOgrInJavaBuildInstructions)
it is written _Note that ​OSGeo4W includes a ​gdal-java package and a Java runtime making it fairly easily to build local Java applications using GDAL._ but I did not find any gdal-java package or any jni library.