# Convert GeoJSON object to GML geometry

Tags: jackson, geojson, gml

I have the following issue with transforming GeoJSON object into GML geometry object.

First, on backend in request I retrieve GeoJSON object. 
Then I use jackson library to transform it into java object. This java object is FeatureCollection from geojson-jackson library.
So I have java object representing GeoJSON on backend and now I need to transform it into GML object and extract geometry from it.

From this:

```
{
  "featureCollection : {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [ [[100.0,0.0],[101.0,0.0],[101.0,1.0],[100.0,1.0],[100.0,0.0]] ]
      },
    }]
  }
}
```

I need to get this:

```
<gml:Rectangle srsName="urn:x-ogc:def:crs:EPSG:6.6:25833">
  <gml:exterior>
    <gml:LinearRing>
      <gml:coordinates>100.0,0.0 101.0,0.0 101.0,1.0 100.0,1.0 100.0,0.0</gml:coordinates>
    </gml:LinearRing>
  </gml:exterior>
</gml:Rectangle>
```

The question, is there any existing library which allows transform from GeoJSON into GML object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is definetly not. You have to find another way to do that.

I suggest you to do that either manually or read it as file and save to variables.

Answer (score 4):

[Geotools can probably do what you need.](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/org/geotools/geojson/geom/GeometryJSON.html)  I would not have posted, since I have not done this, but a speculative recipe is better than "definitely not".

GeoTools can read [GeoJSON](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/org/geotools/geojson/geom/GeometryJSON.html) and give you a JTS geometry or a Feature, which can then be used to generate GML using a [org.geotools.xml.Encoder.](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/org/geotools/xml/Encoder.html)

Use [org.geotools.geojson.feature.FeatureJSON](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/org/geotools/geojson/feature/FeatureJSON.html)  or  [org.geotools.geojson.geom.GeometryJSON](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/org/geotools/geojson/geom/GeometryJSON.html) to take a JSON string and give a Geometry instance, like this:

```
GeometryJSON gJson = new GeometryJSON();
jtsGeometry = gJson.readGeometryCollection(jsonInputStream)
```

Then configure an [encoder](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/org/geotools/xml/Encoder.html) to write GML.

```
org.geotools.xml.Encoder encoder = new org.geotools.xml.Encoder(...);
...
encoder.encode(jtsGeometry, qName, outputStream);
```

I hope this is enough to started.  Perhaps if you get it working (or find it impossible) come back and edit this post.

Comment: Hello. Can you provide an example about that? I am having issues with prefix when encoding a feature collection obtained by FeatureJSON. Thankyou.

Answer (score 2):

As far as i know, there is no such thing for java. ogr2ogr (a commandline utility) can do that:

> converts simple features data between file formats

http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html

```
ogr2ogr -f "GML" destination.gml source.geojson
```

You can run that from java, see this question: [How to run GDAL (ogr2ogr) in Java to convert Shapefiles to GeoJSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27192695/how-to-run-gdal-ogr2ogr-in-java-to-convert-shapefiles-to-geojson)