# How do you write vector files with the GDAL Java bindings?

Tags: java, geospatial, gdal, geo, ogr

I have no trouble reading files of different types using GDAL's Java bindings (version 2.2.1) via the `org.gdal.ogr.ogr.OpenShared(filePath)` method to create a `DataSource`. If I want to create a SQLite file from a DataSource, however, how would I do it?

Looking in the [JavaDocs](http://gdal.org/java/), I've found some `ExportTo` methods on the `Geometry` object that you can use to manually build GeoJSON, WKT, KML and others: http://gdal.org/java/org/gdal/ogr/Geometry.html

There doesn't seem to be anything in the [Driver](http://gdal.org/java/org/gdal/ogr/Driver.html) class that would let you use them to export a DataSource however.

Using ogr2ogr it would be as simple as running the following:

```
ogr2ogr -f "SQLite" ./output.sqlite3 ./input.geojson
```

And there is [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27192695/how-to-run-gdal-ogr2ogr-in-java-to-convert-shapefiles-to-geojson) for running ogr2ogr from within Java, but I would have assumed there'd be something native in the Java bindings.

Answer (score 0):

I've accepted that the best way to do this is to simply include the [ogr2ogr.java file from the GitHub repo](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/trunk/gdal/swig/java/apps/ogr2ogr.java) in my project and wrap it in a function that makes it cleaner to access. It is almost a direct port of the original C++ GDAL file.

The one change I made was to rename the ogr2ogr `main` function to `execute` so that it didn't confuse application when I ran it.